# add method not working for linked list in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to create a method that will add a node to my linked list. The method takes a String. This is the method that I created:

```
    public void add(String x)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.element = x;
        newNode.nextNode = firstNode;
        firstNode = newNode;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't working. Is there a way I can alter it to make it work?

*Here are all the information I was provided with:*

**Linked List Class with Node inner-class:**

```
class LinkedList implements StringCollection
{
 private static class Node
 {

    public String element;
    public Node nextNode;
    public Node (String element)
    {
     this.element = element;
     this.nextNode = null;
    }

 }
 private Node firstNode;
 public NodeStringCollection ()
 {

    firstNode = null;

 }

 //add method goes here

 public String toString ()
 {

    String s = "";
    Node node = firstNode;
    while (node != null)
    {
     s = s + node.element + " ";
     node = node.nextNode;
    }
    return s;

 }
}
```

**Tested Linked Class:**

```
Class Test
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
   StringCollection sc = new LinkedList ();
   sc.add (new String ("A"));
   sc.add (new String ("B"));
   sc.add (new String ("C"));
   sc.add (new String ("D"));
   System.out.println (sc);
   int countStrings = sc.size ();
   System.out.println (countStrings);
  }
}
```

**The Output**

```
D C B A
4
```

Comment: Firstly, it's not clear why you're calling the `String(String)` constructor. Next, your code appears to be working, in that it's adding the new node. It's putting it at the *front* of the list - is that the problem? In what way is the output not what you expect?

Comment: "Unfortunately, this code isn't working" You need to elaborate on this. What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code. What you did wrong is that the element that you added to the `LinkedList` replaced the old `firstNode`. So the last node that you add to your implementation would become the new first node. Therefore, your `LinkedList` printed `D C B A` which is the reverse of what it should be.

The code below stores the first node and the last node. When a new node is added, we let the last node point to the newly created node and then set the last node to the newly created node:

**Code**

```
public class LinkedList {
    public static class Node {
        public String element;
        public Node nextNode;

        public Node(String element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.nextNode = null;
        }

    }

    private Node firstNode;
    private Node lastNode;

    public LinkedList() {
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
    }

    public void add(String x) {
        Node newNode = new Node(x);

        if (firstNode == null)
            firstNode = newNode;
        if (lastNode != null)
            lastNode.nextNode = newNode;
        lastNode = newNode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        Node node = firstNode;
        while (node != null) {
            s = s + node.element + " ";
            node = node.nextNode;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

**Example code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    LinkedList sc = new LinkedList();
    sc.add(new String("A"));
    sc.add(new String("B"));
    sc.add(new String("C"));
    sc.add(new String("D"));
    System.out.println(sc);
}
```

**Output**

```
A B C D
```